# Overlapping multidimensional array corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have a very insidious issue with two dynamically allocated and reallocated multidimensional arrays, defined as follows:

```
int *pRawVals[20][181];
```

and

```
int *pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[20][46];
```

These are allocated in a single function: (code condensed for clarity)

```
... 

// iNlat and iNVer bounds checked and OK
for (int lat = 0; lat < iNlat; lat++)  
{
    pData->pBlendedRawPlanes[lat] = new long long[1 * (iNver + 1)];

    for (int sensor = 0; sensor < 20; sensor++)  
    {
        pData->pRawVals[sensor][lat] = new int[1 * (iNver + 1)];

        for (int vert = 0; vert <= iNver; vert++)  
        {
            pData->pRawVals[sensor][lat][vert] = SENSOR_UNREAD;
        } // end for
    } // end for
} // end for

...

for (int sensor = 0; sensor < 20; sensor++)
{
    delete[] pData->strayVals[sensor];

    pData->strayVals[sensor] = new int[1 * (iNver + 1)];

    for (int vert = 0; vert < iNver + 1; vert++)
    {
        pData->strayVals[sensor][vert] = SENSOR_UNREAD;
    } // end for

    for (int lat = 0; lat < 46; lat++) 
    {
        pData->pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[sensor][lat] = new int[361];

        // for (int iFillMem = 0; iFillMem < 361; iFillMem++)
        for (int vert = 0; vert < iNver; vert++)
        {
            pData->pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[sensor][lat][vert] = SENSOR_UNREAD;
        } // end for
    } // end for 
} // end for

... and deallocated in another function:

for (int lat = 0; lat < pData->iNUserLats; lat++) // iNUserLats <= 181
{
    for (int sensor = 0; sensor < 20; sensor++)
    {
        if (pData->pRawVals[sensor][lat] != NULL)
        {
            delete[] pData->pRawVals[sensor][lat];
            pData->pRawVals[sensor][lat] = NULL;
        } // end if
    } // end for
}

...

for (int sensor = 0; sensor < 20; sensor++)
{
    for (int lat = 0; lat < 46; lat++)
    {
        if (pData->pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[sensor][lat] != NULL)
        {
            delete[] pData->pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[sensor][lat];
            pData->pMaxPlaneRawPlanes[sensor][lat] = NULL;
        } // end if
    } // end for
} // end for
```

Hope I got enough of the code posted. At any rate, when deallocating `pMaxPlaneRawPlanes` on a second pass through the code, it turns out that certain elements of that array overlap elements of `pRawVals` and the deallocation causes a crash - appears that those locations may have been freed previously but I can't seem to point the finger at exactly how it's happening.

Any hints on how to narrow that kind of thing down? I run development on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, but the app is compiled for 32 bit.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `std::array` instead of C style arrays. Consider using `std::vector` instead of manually allocating.

Comment: It seems `pMaxPlaneRawPlanes` always has the exact same dimensions. It would not be necessary to dynamically allocate the last dimension.

Comment: It is not possible to 2 memory block overlaps each other if you created them by new operator. Are you doing some kind of mixing between pRawVals and pMaxPlaneRawPlanes?

Answer (score 0):

You may go out of range in any of your array, or you may go out of range *elsewhere*.

If you are using Visual Studio 2019, or you are using gcc or clang, you can give ASan (Address Sanitizer) a try. ([VS2019 link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/address-sanitizer-for-msvc-now-generally-available/))

Otherwise you can try [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier) with Full Heap check enabled.

It is also possible to use custom allocation and allocate memory the way that it will access violation on out of bounds, even if off by one. It is essentially duplicating Application Verifier for particular allocations.

Using `std::array` or `std::vector` recommended in comments will also help making fewer errors that lead to heap corruption in the first place. `vector` manages deallocations automatically, and also in debug builds may have checks for out-of-range errors.